# Header is not highlighted in type to filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I am using a type to filter textbox,where in yser type the data they want to highlight. The data entered in the textbox is then checked against the row in html table.
Row containing the typed data is shown  and other rows are hidden.

My problem is that this works as expected but the trouble is that it hides the header.Is there any way that it shows the header along with the highlighted row?

Below is the Script I am using :

```
function Search() {

           var value = $('input[id$="txtSearch"]').val();
           if (value) {

               $('#table-2 tr:not(:first:hidden)').each(function () {
                   var index = -1;
                   //$(this).children('td.hiddencls').each(function () {
                   $(this).children('td').each(function () {
                       var text = $(this).text();
                       if (text.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) != -1) {

                           index = 0;

                           return false;
                       }
                   });
                   if (index == 0) {
                       $(this).show();


                   }
                   else {
                       $(this).hide();

                   }
               });

           }
           else
               $('#table-2 tr').show();

       }
```

Kindly provide your valuable suggestions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting this at the end of the Search() definition should work

```
$('#table-2 tr>th').parent().show();
```

(I'm assuming the header row has th tags, instead of td)

Otherwise try this

```
$('#table-2 tr:first').show();
```

Comment: Its just worked :) I was trying by giving id for header and with child..$('#table-2 tr>th').parent().show(); did the magic..Awesome :) Thank u so much

Comment: Glad I could help. You can close the question now.